# structure initialization

Tags: c, arrays, structure

The output of the code has to be zero, but I am having an error, please guide.
I can initialize the structure with its type variable but how can I do with the pointer to initialize the whole structure?

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct student
{
  int roll_id[10];
  int name_id[10];
  int postn;
} student;



int main()
{

  student p; /// here i can do student p={ {0} };

  student *pptr=&p;
  pptr= { {0} };  /// but can i initialize in this way ?? //error: expected       
                      expression before ‘{’ token
  pptr->roll_id[9]=1;
  printf (" %d\n", pptr->postn);   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're assigning `{ {0} }` to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by chris on a comment, you are assigning "something not an integer" to a pointer. You should assign `{ {0} }` instead to the **content** of that pointer (*pointer):

```
*pptr= { {0} }; //bad!
```

Anyway this is not the correct way to populate that structure and you should use:

```
*pptr= (student){ {0}, {0}, 0 };
```

as an example

*edited to solve the error pointed by unwind*

Comment: I think it's valif IF he can do it with the variable. "student p; /// here i can do student p={ {0} };", just wanted to explain the mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C99 or later, you can use [compound literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html). Otherwise you cannot, and must initialize each field separately.

With literals:

```
*pptr = (student) { 0, 0, 0 };
```

without:

```
pptr->roll_id[0] = 0;
pptr->name_id[0] = 0;
pptr->postn = 0;
```

**UPDATE** Edited, for some reason I thought that the `roll_id` and `name_id` fields were strings, but they're not.

It might be easier to just use `memset()` for this, to initialize all the values to zero:

```
memset(pptr, 0, sizeof *pptr);
```

Notice, as always, that this is a fantastic opportunity to use `sizeof` *with the pointer*, since reduces the typing and is easier to read and verify (for reasonable variable names such as we have here).

Comment: I believe you're trying to assign a string literal as an element of an int array.

Comment: @unwind: pptr->roll_id[0-9]=0; // can i do this without loop

Comment: This is wrong! There are no character strings in the question, and braced-enclosed initializer lists are not for assignment.

Comment: @MikeKwan Thanks, must have mis-read the OP's code in some way.

Comment: @acraig5075 Fixed the string mis-match, must have been confused yesterday. But yes, compound literals ("brace-enclosed initializer lists") are fine from C99, as I say.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a 0-initialized structure, you might as well do:

```
struct student *pptr = calloc(1, sizeof(struct student));
```

alternatively, following the code you posted:

```
struct student p;
struct student *pptr = &p;

memset(pptr, 0, sizeof(struct student));
```

of course, these approaches will only work if you want a 0-initialized struct. for anything more facy you'll have to write it out, or use some `memcpy` magic.

Comment: Is it correct to use memset without preallocating (malloc) the actual structure? , for the second case ofcourse in your solution.

Comment: @Sibi you don't have to use malloc in the second example, because pptr points to the memory location of p, which resides in full size on the stack.

Comment: You mean in the stack frame of main()   ?

Comment: @Sibi I'd guess so, since it's a local variable. do you disagree?

Comment: Got you. . And the sizeof(struct student) in memset cleared the doubt I had. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use as below

```
int main()
{

  student p[] = { {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

  student *pptr = p;

  pptr->roll_id[9] = 1;
  printf (" %d\n", pptr->postn);   
  return 0;
}
```

if you want to initialize entire array that is a member of structure , you have to do as like above.